# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling glDrawArrays

Tags: c++, macos, opengl

I am working with OpenGL 3.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.5  I am writing AfterEffects(AE) SDK plugin that uses OpenGL.I create my own rendering context, set it to be current then perform OpenGL API calls.Important to note that there are also other GL contexts around which are created by AE at will, but I don't use those as their are GL2.1.Till now all my plugins worked ok, but a new one fails on :

```
glDrawArrays();
```

with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line :

```
movq   432(%rcx), %rdi
```

I have no clue as this very glDrawArrays() with exactly the same params worked ok on other plugins.I checked that my context is set to be current before this method call but it didn't help.Other GL calls that come prior glDrawArrays()(like uniforms ,FBO and texture bounds) are executed with no errors.I understand that my question has too many unknowns, but What are possible causes for this error?

**UPDATE:**

I went to the shader code and in the fragment shader I found that commenting out "switch" statement solves the crash:

```
     switch (typeCom) {
    case COMP_S:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_L:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_D:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_N:
    default:
        return ///some code;
 };
```

The cases type are defined as global constant integers.typeCom is uniform.This very shader code works fine on Windows and Linux.Does GLSL 150 not support switch?

**UPDATE 2:**

I still haven't found why this crash happens, but at least now I know when it happens.It happens when the case values are variables.If those are explicit numerics there is no problem.So this works:

```
     switch (typeCom) {
    case 0:
        ///some code
        break;
    case 1:
        ///some code
        break;
    case 2:
        ///some code
        break;
    case 3:
    default:
        return ///some code;
 };
```

While this doen't :

```
     switch (typeCom) {
    case COMP_S:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_L:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_D:
        ///some code
        break;
    case COMP_N:
    default:
        return ///some code;
 };
```

Don't know what it is.Compiler bug?Would be nice to get a comment from APPLE GPU driver dudes.

Comment: Support for switch statements was added in GLSL 130... this is a stupid question, but is typeCom also an integer?

Comment: Yes it is also an integer.

Comment: Have you tried whittling down the number of cases in the switch statement? You could be running into register limits, etc. and Apple's GLSL compiler is not doing its job; I assume you looked at the shader/program info log after linking?

Comment: AFAIK SM4 allows up to 64 or 65 thousands instructions and my shader uses like 2% if this number

Comment: The fastest way to see if it's a bug is to run the code on some reference (NVidia, for example) and check behaviour there.

Comment: All my hardware on Windows is NVidia(I target only NVidia for Win/Linux).It works perfect.The issue occurs on Mac's Radeon.

Comment: @MichaelIV: I was not referring to instruction count limits. Whenever you create a variable in GLSL it has to be mapped to a register(s). When you use large arrays or exotic forms of flow control you can run out of temporary registers, and some GLSL compilers don't even bother to warn you about this. I would like to see the actual fragment shader in question here (at least the way every variable is declared), rather than just the switch statement. Apple is going to need this if you want to give them a bug report anyway.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman it is highly possible you are right.In another shader, qith less "exotic" code I get no issues for switch.Sorry, can't show the actual content.It is commercial code.Btw,Do you wanna answer this question?